# Prove the following bound $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-1/2}|f_\epsilon(n)|\lesssim \frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f_\epsilon(x) $ be a smooth function and suppose for all integer $k>0$ there exists some $C_k\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $$|f_\epsilon(x)| \le C_k (1+|\epsilon x|)^{-k}$$

Prove the following bound $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-1/2}|f_\epsilon(n)|\lesssim \frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}$$

Here is the alternative solution after receiving the solution:

This proof is motivated by Gary's comment,As we know for monotone sequence we have the following fact(you may see it from Rudin's first textbook)  $$\sum a_n \sim \sum 2^ka_{2^k}$$

So $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-1/2}|f_\epsilon(n)|\lesssim \sum_{k}(2^k)^{-1/2}(1+\epsilon2^k)^{-N} =  \sum_{k}(2^k)^{-1/2}(\epsilon2^k)^{-N}(1+(\epsilon2^k)^{-1})^{-N}$$ for some sufficient large $N$. RHS is almost a geometric series. We can see if $k>-\log \epsilon$ then $\epsilon2^k$ will dominate 1:

$$\sum_{k\le\log_2\epsilon}(2^k)^{-1/2}(1+\epsilon2^k)^{-N}\lesssim\sum_{k\le -\log_2\epsilon}2^{-k/2}\sim 2^{-1/2\ log_2\epsilon} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}$$

To analyse the tail:

$$\sum_{k\ge -\log_2\epsilon} (2^k)^{-1/2}(\epsilon2^k)^{-N}(1+(\epsilon2^k)^{-1})^{-N}\lesssim\sum_{k\ge -\log_2\epsilon} (2^k)^{-1/2}(\epsilon2^k)^{-N} \sim \epsilon^{-1/2 - 2N}$$

Since N can be arbitary small as the assumption,this tail as function of $\epsilon$ vanish.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: The first thing is the decaying factor makes the sequence converge.

Comment: Hint: Bound the sum by an integral and make a suitable substitution.

Comment: Also, the sum should start with $n=1$.

Comment: @MaoWao Do you mean convert it to Riemann sum?

Comment: First bound the function using the given bound (with $k=1$ say). Then using the monotonicity of the function appearing in the new sum, you can estimate it with an integral. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence#Remark

Comment: @Gary So  thanks I get it.

Comment: you need to split the sum at $n < 100/\epsilon$ (or such) and for that part you use $k=1$ while for $n >100/\epsilon$ you need to use a $k$ depending on $\epsilon$

Comment: @Conrad thanks Can you elaborate more?I can not make it clear ?I mean why the following arguement does not work:fixed $\epsilon$ then use integral to bound the sequence,then gets the result?

Comment: The bound you need is $C_{\epsilon}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}$ while integral bounds will depend on $\epsilon$ so you want to make sure the asymptotic is right; the main term clearly comes from $n << 1/\epsilon$ and it is of the right order, but one has to be careful with the tail (a rough way would be to show that the tail when $n\epsilon >100$ say goes to zero with $k$, or by exhibiting a $k(\epsilon)$

Comment: @yili You should edit your efforts into the question, else it will likely be closed.

Comment: @user1729 thanks I will post alternative proof later.

Comment: @yili That would be good, yes, but you should also edit the question to show some effort etc. Currently, its just the statement of a problem so will be closed (whether you answer it or not).

Comment: @user1729 I have added alternative solution,to monotone sequence can always compare with some geometric series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $k=1$ and note that
\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{\left| {f_\varepsilon  (n)} \right|}}{{\sqrt n }}}  & \le C_1 \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{\sqrt n }}\frac{1}{{1 + \varepsilon n}}}  \le C_1 \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\int_{n - 1}^n {\frac{1}{{\sqrt x }}\frac{1}{{1 + \varepsilon x}}dx} } 
\\ & = C_1 \int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{1}{{\sqrt x }}\frac{1}{{1 + \varepsilon x}}dx} 
\mathop  = \limits^{t = \varepsilon x}  \frac{{C_1 }}{{\sqrt \varepsilon  }}\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{1}{{\sqrt t }}\frac{1}{{1 + t}}dt}  = \frac{{C_1 \pi }}{{\sqrt \varepsilon  }}.
\end{align*}